# IntelliJ IDEA Statistic Plugin "Out of Memory"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm using the [`Statistic`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509) plugin for [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). For one project of mine which has around 15.000 Java source code lines, `Statistic` gets stuck at 92% progress and then `IntelliJ` displays the following `Out of Memory` dialog:

[image]

I tried increasing the memory but that causes [`IntelliJ` to refuse starting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715481/intellij-idea-wont-start) so I had to set the default `512MB`  again.

Why is this caused and how can it be fixed so I can calculate statistics about my project again? Note that the error does not appear with "smaller" projects. In [`TaskManager`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)), `IntelliJ` is at about `980MB` of `RAM` usage but my machine has about `7GB` `RAM` left in total.

Comment: Have you checked that you have enough RAM left in your task manager?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

**TL, DR:** Exclude large files in the *Statistic* plugin settings.

The reason I had this problem was because of many multi-GB datafiles in the project directory. By excluding these large files, the problem was solved.

In the settings of the *Statistic* plugin, you can exclude some file types and/or exclude certain (sub-) directories, to prevent the plugin from trying to read them. If the files are not read, their content is not loaded into memory, preventing the Out of Memory error.

The setting of the *Statistic* plugin are found in its tab (in the bottom left), just beneath the Refresh-button. Alternatively, open them at Pycharm->Preferences->Tools->Statistic.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the `idea.exe.vmoptions` or `idea64.exe.vmoptions` file in your installation directory, and modify the following line to increase the max heap size used by IntelliJ:

```
# Increase max heap size to 2GB.
-Xmx2g
```

Comment: This causes `IntelliJ` to no longer start like described in the question also. My machine has enough `RAM` left though and I can't tell whether `IntelliJ` has a distinction between 32 and 64-bit versions. Apparently, there is just one version so I'm surprised about the startup crash with more memory assigned