# Intellij Idea won't start Windows 10

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I downloaded Intellij Idea and was using it just fine for a while. I don't know what happened between the time it was working and when it started to not work. When I would click the shortcut, my mouse would give me the loading wheel and then nothing would happen. In task manager, there is a task called "IntelliJ Idea" running. I uninstalled and reinstalled twice, and then installed it with the JetBrains toolbox, but this is still happening. I saw another thread about this from 4 years ago, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Other thread: [Intellij IDEA won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715481/intellij-idea-wont-start)

Comment: Does it run via `bin\idea.bat` file? Can you post the full console log of the startup when you run with the .bat file? You may have `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` or `_JAVA_OPTIONS` set which load some third-party agent or provide incompatible options breaking IDE startup. See if [removing IDE folders helps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559).

Comment: For me `bat` file works fine. But 64bit `.exe` file is not working.

Comment: I have the same issue with the `.bat` working but `.exe` not working.  Did you ever solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post this since I recently came across a similar issue with IntelliJ IDE Community Edition but for MacOS and it seems like the same issue could potentially happen on Windows.

I was using the JetBrains Toolbox to manage the installations and updates and after a recent update, when trying to start the app it would simply attempt to start and get killed straight away. After not having much luck with the logs I eventually found the exception that was being thrown when it attempted to start:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/intellij/util/lang/PathClassLoader has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

So from this I realized that the app was trying to run with an older version of Java and I found how to change it in [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879) post. In my case the 'idea.jdk' file was located in '/Users/*user*/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2' and for some reason was not updated after the application update.