# Intellij is not starting on windows 10

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, ide

I start it, it loads for barely a second, that's it. Nothing opens whatsoever. I tried reinstalling it multiple times using both the download from the website and the jetbrains toolbox. I did even reinstall java. I found the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59995379/intellij-idea-wont-start-windows-10) but the question did not get answers. I can start intellij using the bin\idea.bat file but not using the idea64.exe file. No idea why this happens. I am using java version 15.0.2, theoretically intellij IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2 on windows 10.

Comment: if you start from command line. Do you see any error ? You can also find error information in intellij log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe and see if it helps.

Comment: Very helpful, this worked and I accidentally deleted these files yesterday, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that it helped, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170 for a list of the latest