# IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 won't start

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Version 2020.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it is not starting. I tried running it from the terminal, the following error is shown:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Unrecognized option: -ide.win.frame.decoration=true
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The unrecognized option was added by me, to remove the title bar. But after adding this option and restarting it, it fails to start.
    I thought this option might be located in "idea.vmoptions" file but could not find it there. Is there any other file where this option might be located? Or is there any way to start IntelliJ ignoring this error?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715481/intellij-idea-wont-start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there are multiple "idea.vmoptions" files. I had to edit the one in:

```
/home/user_name/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.1
```

I had to remove "-ide.win.frame.decoration=true" from there. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`.vmoptions` file takes options in this format: `-D<option>=<value>`.

The syntax for the option you've inserted was invalid, should have been `-Dide.win.frame.decoration=true` instead.

See [this FAQ document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869) for the details how this file can be found and edited manually depending on the OS and IDE version.