# IntelliJ IDEA: Abnormal build process termination after heap size change

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-size

I've been trying to allocate 256MB array, which produced Java heap space exception. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17221838) and it didn't help. So I've been looking for another similar problems and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36518169). However, after raising the heap size above 1377MB i get this error:

> Error:Abnormal build process termination:  "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Xmx1377m -Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/CacheTest -Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/JohnDoe/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/options
>   -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-2473188797876308560 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1250 -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2016.1 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\JohnDoe.IntelliJIdea2016.1\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\JohnDoe.IntelliJIdea2016.1\config\plugins
>   -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/JohnDoe/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/log/build-log
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/JohnDoe/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/compile-server/*temp*
>   -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\JOHNDO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-1150430122745838-is-running\"
>   -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/ecj-4.5.2.jar"
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jsr166e.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/asm-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ
>   IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ
>   IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ
>   IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/netty-all-4.1.0.Beta8.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/picocontainer.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/lib/snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/openapi.jar;;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-2.9.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/jna-3.2.7.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/gson-2.5.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/osmorc-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bndlib-3.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bndlib-plugins-3.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bundlor-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/javaee-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/dmServer/lib/dmServer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/GwtStudio/lib/gwt-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/google-app-engine-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/appEngine-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-compiler-patch.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2016.1.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 60896
>   96c068b6-4d3b-4924-a696-9af1caab47b3
>   C:/Users/JohnDoe/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/compile-server

I've found many answers to such problem, but all of them are telling me to downgrade my NVIDIA driver which I'm not able to do and which doesn't make sense to me at all. What I'm looking for is the some sort of explanation why this is happening and what could I do to solve it.

Note: I'm using x64 IDEA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your project JSDK to 64-bit version, you are building and running with 32-bit JDK right now which cannot allocate more than 2GB RAM on Windows. Because of the other JVM requirements, the real maximum heap size for the 32-bit JVM is usually between 512m and 1024m.

You can find more details in [IntelliJ IDEA FAQ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241105) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13489882/104891).

Answer (score 0):

I was also having same problem. In my case Android Support was not enabled (File>> Settings>> Android Support). Once I enabled and restarted Android Studio everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows x64 bit machine. I was facing similar kind of problem. What I would suggests is first create a simple java application and I try executing it, if you see that the problem persists then try uninstalling the existing JDK and reinstall from this [link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/).

Else, if your test application seems to work fine, then there is some issue with your project JDK path or module settings. Try reimporting the project and check if the JDK path is provided correctly

Answer (score 0):

File->Project structure->on SDK field change jdk version to higher